# Random int in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random

I just wrotte the code below in C++, but I have one problem: the random number that cames it's always the same..!!
Here's my code and a screenshot:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "I got a number in my mind... can you guess it?" << endl;
    int random;
    random = rand() % 20 + 1;

    cout << random << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

screenshot : http://tinyurl.com/n49hn3j

Comment: You have to seed the random number generator in the beginning of the program. Include cstdlib header and add srand( time(0) ); in the beginning of your main function.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal +1, try srand(time(0));

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand

Comment: an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21724736/2567683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to init (seed) the random using the `srand` function. [more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Seed the random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    cout << "I got a number in my mind... can you guess it?" << endl;

    int random;
    random = rand() % 20 + 1;

    cout << random << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: result is biased though

Answer (score 12):

`srand(time(0))` will only produce a new random number if you do not start it in the same second you did the last time. Also there are [issues with using rand() % 20](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). This will do the right thing:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <random> 
int main(){ 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 20);
    std::cout << dist(mt);
}
```

Comment: importing the whole `std` `namespace` isn't always a good idea if you're only using a small part of it. just my $0.02

Comment: @IosifM. True. I though I can get away with it because its just inside a function and a code example, but of course it should be done right. I fixed it.

Comment: +1 for using the c++11 version and not propagating the mess that is rand()

Comment: @nwp: didn't mean to be a code nazi, just wanted to throw that out so that the OP would have this in mind. anyway, gj as dutt said

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
#include <ctime>  //for current time 
#include <cstdlib> //for srand
    srand (unsigned(time(0))); //use this seed
```

This will also work for your random.